# How to print using letterpaper from auto-multiple-choice

Tags: letters, printing, paper, auto-multiple-choice

I have prepared an exam in auto-multiple-choice (AMC) and formatted the document to use letterpaper, rather than the default a4paper. However, when I go to print individual (serial) copies of the exam directly to a printer, AMC seems to insist on using a4 paper. I have tried starting the document with

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]
```

but that does not fix the problem. I have tried placing a call to

```
\geometry{letterpaper}
```

immediately before `\begin{document}`, but that doesn't work either. I end up having to "print" to individual pdf documents, and then drag those pdf documents to the printer icon (macos) to print the individual exam copies. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in AMC?

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange.com. In order to help with your problem, could you provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE) that reproduce the error/problem you need to solve? Thanks!

Comment: How do you print exam copies? Using auto-multiple-choice or directly from the .pdf file?

Comment: I installed the developer version of AMC using homebrew. I was attempting to print from within AMC directly to a printer, rather than to individual pdf files for subsequent printing. However, the printer (Canon imageRunner advance 8595i) consistently complained that it needed a custom paper size and then printed with an excessive top margin such that the bottom two fiducial dots were not printed. On the other hand, if I print to individual pdf files, they print just fine.

Comment: So your source file is ok: you have to change the way AMC print these files. Then maybe AMC's forum will be a better place to find help.